# Create Json using custom attributes in c# using newtonsoft json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, poco

I would like to create a custom Json object from C# POCO classes, the structure of Json object would be derived from custom attributes applied onto the classes, below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Below are few sample classes

```
    public class SomeBaseClass
    {
        public int BaseId { get; set; }

        public string SomeBaseProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class NestedClass
    {
        public string SomeNestedProp1 { get; set; }
        public string SomeNestedProp2 { get; set; }
    }

    [ModelType(TargetModule.COMPLAINT, ModelAffinity.PARENT)]
    public class ChildOne : SomeBaseClass
    {
        public ChildOne()
        {
            NestedClasses = new List<NestedClass>();
            nestedClassesAgain = new List<NestedClass>();
        }

        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
        public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }

        [ModelType(TargetModule.COMPLAINT, ModelAffinity.NESTED)]
        public IList<NestedClass> NestedClasses { get; set; }

        public IList<NestedClass> nestedClassesAgain { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is a sample custom attribute which is used above.

```
    [Serializable]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class ModelType : Attribute
    {
        public ModelType(TargetModule targetModule, ModelAffinity modelAffinity)
        {
            TargetModuleName = targetModule;

            ModelAffinityType = modelAffinity;
        }

        public TargetModule TargetModuleName { get; }

        public ModelAffinity ModelAffinityType { get; }
    }

    public enum TargetModule
    {
        COMPLAINT,

        PAYMENT,

        RECEIPTS
    }

    public enum ModelAffinity
    {
        PARENT,

        NESTED,
    }
```

Below is the Json object I plan to create using the custom attributes.

```
{
 "complaint": {
  "someproperty": "sample value",
  "someproperty1": "sample value1",
  "someproperty2": "sample value2",
  "baseid": "123",
  "somebaseproperty": "sample value3"
  "nested": [{
    "somenestedprop1": "sample nested value1",
    "somenestedprop2": "sample nested value2"
   }
  ],
  "nestedclassesagain": [{
    "somenestedprop1": "sample nested again value1",
    "somenestedprop2": "sample nested again value2"
   }]
  }
 }
```

In the above output the properties / classes containing custom attribute are converted into their values i.e. the property "NestedClasses" is converted into the attribute value "nested", if the other property "NestedClassesAgain" contained the same attribute then the values / properties would get merged into the "nested" Json Array object.

Something like below

```
"nested": [{
    "somenestedprop1": "sample nested value1",
    "somenestedprop2": "sample nested value2"
   },
   {
    "somenestedprop1": "sample nested again value1",
    "somenestedprop2": "sample nested again value2"
   }
  ]
```

Tried achieving this using custom ContractResolver as below

```
    public class AttributeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> configDerivedList;

        public AttributeContractResolver()
        {
            configDerivedList = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "ChildOne", "BaseId,SomeProperty,SomeProperty1,NestedClasses,nestedClassesAgain" },
                { "ChildTwo", "BaseId,SomeBaseProperty,SomeOtherProperty1,SomeOtherProperty2" },
                { "NestedClass", "SomeNestedProp1, SomeNestedProp2"},
                { "COMPLAINT", "BaseId,SomeProperty,SomeProperty1,SomeNestedProp1" },
            };
        }

        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

            IEnumerable<(ModelType[] attributes, string propWithAttribute)> tt = (from x in base.GetSerializableMembers(type)
                                                                                  where x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ModelType), false).Length > 0
                                                                                  let attributes = (ModelType[])x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ModelType), false)
                                                                                  let propWithAttribute = x.Name
                                                                                  select (attributes, propWithAttribute));

            var moduleType = (ModelType[])type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ModelType), false);

            List<string> requiredProperties = (from key in configDerivedList
                                               where moduleType.All(mod => mod
                                                   .TargetModuleName
                                                   .ToString() == key.Key) &&
                                                tt.All(a => a
                                                    .attributes
                                                    .All(mod => mod
                                                        .TargetModuleName
                                                        .ToString() == key.Key))
                                               select key).FirstOrDefault().Value.Split(',').ToList();

            requiredProperties.AddRange(from propss in properties
                                        from t in tt
                                        where propss.PropertyName == t.propWithAttribute
                                        select propss.PropertyName);

            properties = properties.Where(prop => requiredProperties.Contains(prop.PropertyName, new StringComparer())).ToList();

            return properties;
        }
    }
```

In the sample converter above, I would also like to serialize properties based on the attribute values, i.e. selective properties based on the attributes set on the classes.

Hope I could elaborate the use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do that at all instead of actually creating the object structure you want? A serializer's job is simply to serialize data, not to transform the data from one form to another.

Comment: If you want to map between types you could use eg AutoMapper or just write the mapping code. The way this question is written it's hard to understand what the two structures look like though. `complaint` is the name of a property in JSON, why should it be specified through an *attribute*? Why not use an anonymous type eg  `new {complaint = new WhateverTheRootIs{}}` ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, the idea is to create a structure based on the attributes applied on the class, in a real world application scenario, the classes would be defined on a client application which would have access to the custom attribute class, the client application would serialize the class & push to a queue, the queue receiver would not know the structure of the class that created the json, hence was thinking of creating a json structure upfront so that the receiver does not worry about an expected schema

Comment: You could relate this to applying an xslt to an xml & transforming it to a specific structure, if this isn't possible, are there any other ways to achieve something similar, the base idea is to convert into a specific json structure depending upon a pre-defined type (in this example i used a custom attribute), any suggestions would help, Thanks again for your response

Comment: Again, *why*? What you describe is just mapping. You gain nothing by doing it using hard-coded attributes. Mappings can be defined at runtime where attributes are hard-coded at compile time. Might as well share DTOs instead of attributes. In fact, that would be a *lot* more flexible than trying to force entity models to work as DTOs

Comment: JSON means you *don't* care about attributes and properties anyway. You can pop a string from a queue and deserialize it to a JObject or a `dynamic` variable and use it, as long as you know what the attribute names are. Or you can deserialize it to a DTO that uses just the attributes you care about.

Comment: You can map objects based on attributes using the [AutoMapper.Attributes](https://github.com/schneidenbach/AutoMapper.Attributes) extension to AutoMapper, and map your entity objects to the DTOs that match the schema you want.